# Fragment's onViewCreated() get called when parent activity finish()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, lifecycle

So, I have an activity that serves as a container for some fragments. This activity has a navigation drawer to help user navigating between fragments.

One of the fragments (in this case, it is called HomeFragment), when loaded, will fetch some data from a server, and then putting them into a ListView inside the HomeFragment. This process is done in onViewCreated().

Now, the problem is, when I finish the activity, the onViewCreated of HomeFragment somehow gets called. But because when the fragment fetched the data from the server the activity already finished, it fails to find view to put the data into. This crashes the app.

My MainActivity.java (that contains the fragment):

```
    public void setDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem){
        ...
        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.logout) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        ...
    }
```

So when the user log out, the MainActivity will finish, and LoginActivity will start.

In my HomeFragment:

```
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.home_listView);

        //fill aspiration_list with aspirations from database, then populate listview
        new AspirationGetAll().execute();
    }
```

The AspirationGetAll class is an ASyncTask that will fetch the data from database, and populate the listview.

Logcat:

```
11-19 01:49:05.408 14290-14290/com.jefsolution.yourvote E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-19 01:49:05.408 14290-14290/com.jefsolution.yourvote E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.jefsolution.yourvote, PID: 14290
11-19 01:49:05.408 14290-14290/com.jefsolution.yourvote E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
11-19 01:49:05.408 14290-14290/com.jefsolution.yourvote E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.jefsolution.yourvote.Fragment.HomeFragment$AspirationGetAll.onPostExecute(HomeFragment.java:179)
11-19 01:49:05.408 14290-14290/com.jefsolution.yourvote E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.jefsolution.yourvote.Fragment.HomeFragment$AspirationGetAll.onPostExecute(HomeFragment.java:147)
11-19 01:49:05.408 14290-14290/com.jefsolution.yourvote E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
11-19 01:49:05.408 14290-14290/com.jefsolution.yourvote E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
11-19 01:49:05.408 14290-14290/com.jefsolution.yourvote E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
11-19 01:49:05.408 14290-14290/com.jefsolution.yourvote E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-19 01:49:05.408 14290-14290/com.jefsolution.yourvote E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-19 01:49:05.408 14290-14290/com.jefsolution.yourvote E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5260)
11-19 01:49:05.408 14290-14290/com.jefsolution.yourvote E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-19 01:49:05.408 14290-14290/com.jefsolution.yourvote E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-19 01:49:05.408 14290-14290/com.jefsolution.yourvote E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-19 01:49:05.408 14290-14290/com.jefsolution.yourvote E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
11-19 01:49:06.778 14290-14290/com.jefsolution.yourvote I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14290 SIG: 9
```

The app works fine when not clicking the logout button in the drawer.
Line 179 in HomeFragment is:

```
AspirationAdapter adapter = new AspirationAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), aspiration_list);
```

Line 147 is the declaration of class AspirationGetAll.

This is the method that handle navigation drawer item click. Is there anything that can possibly trigger the HomeFragment lifecycle all over again (therefore calling onViewCreated()) when clicking on logout?

```
 public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on

        // position

        Fragment fragment = null;

        Class fragmentClass;
        switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.home_fragment:
                fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.trending_fragment:
                fragmentClass = TrendingFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.my_aspiration_fragment:
                fragmentClass = MyAspirationFragment.class;
                break;
            default:
                fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
        }
        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.logout) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer

        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        mDrawer.closeDrawers();
    }
```

Comment: did u forget to put break on default case or forgot to paste the line here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to hit the web  service  when the view is created i.e in

```
onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)
{
    ...
}
```

`onViewCreated` is called immediately after `onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)` has returned, but before any saved state has been restored in to the view. This gives subclasses a chance to initialize themselves once they know their view hierarchy has been completely created. And the primary reason for null pointer exception is due to inavailability of the Context in the adapter view. Have you tried using `getActivity()` instead of `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` ?

Comment: If I put it in onCreateView, wouldn't it not find any view? Because the layout is not inflated yet.

I tried using getActivity(), still got an error. But this time, it's on pDialog.dismiss() in onPostExecute(). Still, this means that onViewCreated() is still called when I tried to logout.

Comment: have you instantiate pDialog object

Comment: Not a recommended way of hitting web service in onCreateView